# How to use Perl to write a script to convert one table into another?

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a Perl script to convert Table 1 into Table 2:

Table 1

```
1   rs2905037-G-A   0   775426
1   rs6701114-C-T   0   1022037
2   SNP1-G-T    0   2
10  rs7918734-C-A   0   192533
10  rs1476129-A-C   0   265520
10  rs1476130-T-A   0   274675
10  rs17221239-C-G  0   285113
23  rs17537524-C-A  0   816304
23  rs17461767-G-A  0   2335503
24  SNP2-T-C    0   48
```

Table 2

```
chr1    dbSNP   SNV 775426  775426  20  +   0   rs2905037-G-A
chr1    dbSNP   SNV 1022037 1022037 20  +   0   rs6701114-C-T
chr2    dbSNP   SNV 2   2   20  +   0   SNP1-G-T
chr10   dbSNP   SNV 192533  192533  20  +   0   rs7918734-C-A
chr10   dbSNP   SNV 265520  265520  20  +   0   rs1476129-A-C
chr10   dbSNP   SNV 274675  274675  20  +   0   rs1476130-T-A
chr10   dbSNP   SNV 285113  285113  20  +   0   rs17221239-C-G
chrX    dbSNP   SNV 816304  816304  20  +   0   rs17537524-C-A
chrX    dbSNP   SNV 2335503 2335503 20  +   0   rs17461767-G-A
chrY    dbSNP   SNV 48  48  20  +   0   SNP2-T-C
```

I have tried to use this code below....however ...it is only placing both of the tables in a new text file. I would like to convert the format that is in Table 1 into the format that is in Table 2.

```
@docList = glob ('*');
open(OUTPUT, ">combined.txt");
foreach $filename(@docList) {
    open(INPUT, $filename);
    print OUTPUT <INPUT>;
    close(INPUT);
}
close(OUTPUT);
```

I need a Perl script to convert Table 1 into Table 2?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Please include the tables as text in your question. It enables easy cut and paste, and makes your question valid if the external data should be removed in the future

Comment: Hi ...were you able to see the pics of the tables that I attached?I have tried using this code below but it only combines both tables into one text file. I would like to convert the format that is in Table 1 into the format that is in Table 2.  @docList = glob ('*');

open(OUTPUT, ">combined.txt");

foreach $filename(@docList) {

 open(INPUT, $filename);

 print OUTPUT <INPUT>;

 close(INPUT);

}

close(OUTPUT);

Comment: Try this: `perl -anE 'say join "\t", "chr$F[0]", "dbSNP", "SNV", $F[3], 20, "+", 0, $F[1] ' table1.txt`

Comment: Hi...I am new at learning Perl. Where would I insert your code in the code that I listed above?

Comment: You have to modify the input before you write it to the output handle. First split each line on space into fields, then combine new fields as I showed, and finally print new line to file

Comment: I am not sure if this is what I should do? and how would I convert the input into the output?                                                 
open (FILE, "Table1.txt");
print <FILE>;

open(OUTPUT, "Table2.txt");
foreach $filename(@docList){
 open (INPUT, $filename);
 print OUTPUT <INPUT>;

while (<FILE>) 
   'chomp;
   my @f = split /\t/;
   'say join "\t",
      "chr".$f[0],
      "dbSNP",
      "SNV",
      $f[3],
      $f[3],
      "20",
      "+",
      $f[2],
      $f[1]';
}
print <FILE>;

 close (INPUT);

close (OUTPUT)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<$INPUT>) {
   chomp;
   my @f = split /\t/;
   say $OUTPUT join "\t",
      "chr".$f[0],
      "dbSNP",
      "SNV",
      $f[3],
      $f[3],
      "20",
      "+",
      $f[2],
      $f[1];
}
```

Comment: Hi...where would I insert your code in the one below?                                      
@docList = glob ('*');
open(OUTPUT, ">combined.txt");
foreach $filename(@docList) {
    open(INPUT, $filename);
    print OUTPUT <INPUT>;
    close(INPUT);
}
close(OUTPUT);

Comment: First of all, don't use global variables. Use `open(my $OUTPUT, ...)`. You can specify the handle from which `<>` reads by placing it within (`<$INPUT>`). As for telling `say` where to output? That's one's trivial to find in the docs.

Comment: Ok...this is what I put together, but I am still learning perl..so everything is relatively new to me.                                                                               
open (FILE, "Table1.txt");
print <FILE>;

open(OUTPUT, "Table2.txt");
foreach $filename(@docList){
 open (INPUT, $filename);
 print OUTPUT <INPUT>;

while (<FILE>) 
   'chomp;
   my @f = split /\t/;
   'say join "\t",
      "chr".$f[0],
      "dbSNP",
      "SNV",
      $f[3],
      $f[3],
      "20",
      "+",
      $f[2],
      $f[1]';
}
print <FILE>;

 close (INPUT);

close (OUTPUT)

Comment: @Z.Johns Please don't put large amounts of code into comments. Instead, please edit your question to add the new code.